# Mysql query max value corresponding field

Tags: mysql, max

I wanted to get the corresponding field for a max value. So I want to show the actualOffence that has the highest crime count in that borough.

Here is the what i have tried. Im not sure if i am using case properly.

```
SELECT b.boroughName, 
       actualOffence( CASE WHEN MAX(c.crimeCount)), (c.crimeCount)
  FROM FYP_Borough b 
        JOIN FYP_Crime c 
          ON b.boroughID=c.boroughID 
        JOIN FYP_Offence o  
          ON c.offenceID=o.offenceID
 GROUP BY b.boroughName
```

Comment: What is `actualOffence` a column? A function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get the max `crimeCount` per `boroughname` in a subquery and then `join` accordingly.  If I'm understanding your data structure correctly, this should work:

```
SELECT b.boroughName, 
    o.actualOffence,
    c.crimeCount
FROM (SELECT b2.boroughID, b2.boroughname, max(c2.crimecount) maxcrimecount
      FROM FYP_Borough b2
          JOIN FYP_Crime c2 ON b2.boroughID=c2.boroughID 
      GROUP BY b2.boroughID, b2.boroughName
    ) b JOIN FYP_Crime c ON b.boroughID=c.boroughID AND b.maxcrimecount = c.crimecount
        JOIN FYP_Offence o ON c.offenceID=o.offenceID
```

Comment: It say Unknown column 'b.boroughID' in 'on clause'

Comment: @armze3 -- I edited my answer about 5 minutes ago -- did you try the updates?  I originally left that column out of the subquery but noticed after I posted the answer...